# Issues with the installation of "discord-components"

Tags: python, discord.py

I've tried to install discord-components for a long time but always had the same error:

> "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> discord-components (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for discord-components"

To install it, I run `"pip install --upgrade discord-components"` in my command prompt.

My current version of discord.py is 1.7.3, I also tried using the version 2.0.1 but it brought a lot of issues to my programs and did not fix my issue in dowloading discord-components so I went back to 1.7.3.

My current version of python is 3.10.6.

My question is, does anyone know how to fix this issue, and if so, how? Or is there any other way to use buttons and select menus?

Comment: It seems like the discord-components package is no longer developed since 2021, and thus has no Python 3.10 support. Try downgrading to Python 3.9. However, I personally would *really* recommend using discord.py 2.0 instead. Here's a guide that will help you migrate: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html

Comment: Is there any other way to use buttons or select menus?

Comment: You can use buttons or menus by using the original discord.py library as @moinierer3000 mentioned.